Printdialog print in bold on Windows 10 but does not print in bold on Windows 11
Good evening,
I’m trying to solve this puzzle.
I wrote in C# a function to prints a FlowDocument on a printer.
The FlowDocument is first paginated with tables and sections with different font properties depending on the section.
In practice depending on the section, I decide what font size to assign and whether it should print in bold or regular.
My problems is that when I launch the function from pc with Windows 10 or with Windows 11 updated from 10 the bold is printed correctly, but if I do it on native pc Windows 11 no.
It’s crazy that only bold is not printed, while the font size is changed.
This is the print function I created
private static bool PrintDocument(FlowDocument Doc, string PrinterName, int Copie, int OrderCode)
{
    string txt = "";
    string str = "";
    IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = Doc;
    System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog prnt = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
    try
    {
        prnt.PrintQueue = new PrintQueue(new PrintServer(), PrinterName);
        for (int j = 0; j < Copie; j++) prnt.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, str); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string txtErr = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "; " + ex.Message + ";";
        Utility.LogEvent(txtErr);
    }
    
    return true;
}


can you help me?
I tried to include WindowsBase and PresentationCore but among the references but visual studio gives me error.
I also install the VCredist x64 and x86 but nothing has changed.
I also compiled on pc with Windows 11 and with Windows 10 but nothing.

BTW What is the reason for returning a result from a method when it will always return true? Even when an exception is raised it will be catched and the result is still true. I guess this is one of the main things I will never understood. Can you shed a light on this why you think this is a good design?

It always comes true because after the execution of this function I call another that completes the last operations.
Any exceptions I save in a log file with the LogEvent function. So I don’t stop running. The problem is running the printDocument that takes a DocumentiPaginator and does not print it in bold only on Windows 11

That was exact my point: The return value has no information. The method may have succeded or not - the result will always be true. If that method would return void (nothing) it would be the same quality. But I do not understand what drives people to design such methods with useless result values instead of void
